# Number of combinations of combinations depending on set and element sizes

Tags: co.combinatorics

Since some days, I'm trying to simplify a recursive and long algorithm into a fast (non recursive) equation taking 3 parameters into account.

*I want to precise that I don't know really how to specify my problem in one question (I don't know well mathematical combinatorials vocabulary). I will try to be as much understandable as possible. Please let me know if I use wrong vocabulary or if something I said can be simplified using mathematics vocab.*

So, my question can be explained with the following problem for example:

> There is a game that can be played from 2 to an infinite number of teams.
>   Each team should be composed by the same number of players.
>   A player cannot be in 2 different teams during one game at the time.
>
> There is a certain amount of players (lets say `P`).
>   I want to find the equation `f(P,T,S)=y` as `y` is the number of different games rounds we can make, specifying the number of teams who will play (`T`) against each others, and the number of players by team (`S` for team Sizes).

For example, let say there are `P=5` players.
If I want the numbers of combinations as there is `T=2` teams of `S=2` players, the equation should be `f(P=5,T=2,S=2)=15` as we can do the following combinations:

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}, {{1,2},{3,5}}, {{1,2},{4,5}}
{{1,3},{2,4}}, {{1,3},{2,5}}, {{1,3},{4,5}}
{{1,4},{2,3}}, {{1,4},{2,5}}, {{1,4},{3,5}}
{{1,5},{2,3}}, {{1,5},{2,4}}, {{1,5},{3,4}}
{{2,3},{4,5}}, {{2,4},{3,5}}, {{2,5},{3,4}}
```

(Maybe I've the wrong notations, so note that `{1,2}` and `{2,1}` are representing the same subset (same "Team" for the example problem), and that `{{1,2},{3,4}}` and `{{3,4},{1,2}}` are representing the same set (the same "game round"))

Following, some results I expect (hand made calculation)
[image: expected]

---

I found some partial equations for now:

With S=1 fixed, I've found that: $f(P,T,1)={P \choose T}=\frac{P!}{T!(P-T)!}$

With T=1 fixed, I've found that: $f(P,1,S)={P \choose S}=\frac{P!}{S!(P-S)!}$

With T=2 and S=2, I've found that: $f(P,2,2)={{P \choose 2} \choose 2}=\frac{P!}{8((P-4)!)}$ ([Tri-triangular numbers](https://oeis.org/A050534))

I'm pretty sure there is a function that gather these 3 I've found into only one, taking P, T and S as a variable.
But I have difficulties to find it.

Thank you for any help, if you need more information please ask for !

Comment: This is studied as part of combinatorial design theory, sometimes under a name like tournament scheduling or team assignment.  I would start with the Handbook of Combinatorial Designs and see what references they recommend.  In my opinion, in general f is unknown, and provable bounds are weak.  Gerhard "Is Mathematics A Team Sport?" Paseman, 2018.01.08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking $S$ players from $P$ for the first team, we have
$${P \choose S} = \frac{P!}{S!(P-S)!}$$
choices.
We are left with $P-S$ players to pick from for the second team, so for a total of $T$ teams, we would have
$$\prod_{i=0}^{T-1} {P-iS \choose S}$$ choices, assuming of course that $ST \leq P$.
But now we count a little bit too much, in your example we would count $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ twice, once as $\{1,2\},\{3,4\}$ and once as $\{3,4\},\{1,2\}$. If we have $T$ teams, there are $T!$ ways to order them, we count them all but only want one. Therefore, the final formula is
$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{T-1} {P-iS \choose S}}{T!} = \prod_{j = 1}^T \frac{(P-jS+S)!}{S!(P-jS)!j} = \ldots.$$

I am sure you can simplify this further if needed.

Comment: Thank you ! for information, I could reduce this into the following: $ f(P,T,S)= \frac{P!}{T! S!^T (P-TS)!} $, and after test, it seems to work well !